# Android FM Radio using OmapZoom source code Error

Tags: android, android-intent, android-ndk, omap, android-ndk-r7

I downloaded the code from git://git.omapzoom.org/platform/hardware/ti/wpan.git to do the FMRadio in android.
But while importing the app FmRxApp its showing compilation errors.
Can any one help me how to import this app who already worked on this FM radio app.

Thanks & Regards
Tiru

Answer (score 0):

check this http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?s=54fdb869bb59f8f7150a94f032d11554&t=2198686&page=48   is made with same files by me